# How to expand the treeview by a fullpath?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I think this is common in treeview, it has a number of level, and I have a path, say:

```
Level1 > Level2 > Level3 > Level4
```

How can I expand the treeview to Level 4 by using the path? Any built-in function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Purely based on documentation

```
TreeNode mynode = treeView1.FindNode(pathToNode);
mynode.Select();
mynode.Expand();
```

I hope you get the starting point from here.

Comment: Does not work, will not expand child because thevchild is still hidden. Also question wants all nodes expanded.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still common...

```
node.ExpandParentNodes();
```

This will go through parent using recursion and expand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Expand(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim objNode As TreeNode
    Dim preNode As TreeNode = tFolder.Nodes(0)

    preNode.Expand()

    Dim sSpl() As String = sPath.Replace("\\", "\").Split("\")

    For i As Integer = 1 To sSpl.Length - 1

        For Each objNode In preNode.Nodes
            If objNode.Text = sSpl(i) Then
                objNode.Expand()
                preNode = objNode
                Exit For

            End If
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```